# Internet connectivity on Server 2008 VM is strangely inconsistent

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, vmware-esxi

I have a very strange problem on one of my VMs. This VM is running on ESXi 4.1 as are all my other VMs. On this particular machine though I am not able to reach some sites at all, others very slowly, and others normally. To give you some examples bing.com and google.com load normally, espn.com and jetreports.com don't load at all, and slashdot.org loads very slowly.

On any other computer on the network, VM or otherwise, everything loads fine and at a normal pace.

I've tried disabling Windows' firewall with no change in results (as would be expected).

I have a very simple networking setup in my virtual environment. This VM, like others, has two NICs: one for the production network and one for my SAN.

One other thing to mention is that pinging any website always returns an IP address but does not always return with successful pings.

Any ideas out there for troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using vmxnet3 for the network adapter type and are vmware tools installed and up to date on this particular VM?

I think vmware recommends the vmxnet3 driver for server 2008 but I could be wrong.

Something to try though, that is what I use on my server 2008 VM's and I have never had any networking problems.

Comment: I generally keep the settings at their defaults but that's not to say I've done something I can't remember but they are mostly E1000. I did a spot check of a few VMs and there were just a few that had vmxnet3.

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas-

- Check basic network settings like subnet mask, gateway, routing tables, et cetera.
- Check your router to see if there are any rules that would affect web browsing or general packet routing for this host
- Check to see if you reused an address that already has a rule set up in your firewall
- To verify whether or not the ping failures are valid, try from a known good server. Sometimes web hosts block ping requests.
- Try a traceroute against the IP addresses that both succeed and are confirmed to fail to see where the packets die
- If you can, use a utility like wget ([Win32 port here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)) or a simple telnet session ([instructions here](http://www.esqsoft.com/examples/troubleshooting-http-using-telnet.htm)) to get the website directly and rule out a browser issue

If none of the above are able to help you find an answer, run a packet sniffer while browsing a failing page on the server (with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or some such) and compare it against the results of a known good server.

Comment: I think you may be on to something...

I can see that tracert on google.com makes it way through my ISP and then through different IPs until reaching its destination.

tracert on espn.com (from the server) times out at the 1st hop.

tracert on espn.com (from my workstation) works similarly to how google.com did.

Any further thoughts? I'm afraid my networking knowledge is quite limited.

Comment: It seems most likely that something on your firewall/router (whatever is first hop) is blocking it, then.

Comment: I've tried to use Wireshark but I'm afraid it hasn't shown me anything that I can decipher.